# My joomla component view doesn't load in the template

Tags: joomla

I got a component that doesn't load in the template.

http://nicerchoice.com/index.php/juste-un-autre-bouton

All the other views from the component load perfectly except that one.

http://nicerchoice.com/index.php/juste-un-autre-bouton?view=campaigns etc.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

It needs the `?view=campaigns` postfix of th url to work.Look at chrome console

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: PaymentMethods is not defined .
```

So initialization of the component is failed.Try to filter this link if you have a seo component and is enabled.If there is a bug that do not assign this postfix at a menu item create a link type item instead and add the url :

```
index.php/juste-un-autre-bouton?view=campaigns
```

Comment: On a clean install with no Seo component or other components it gave me the same problems. How can i investigate the initialization of the component? Could it be a missing phase in the installation process? Thk for the help.

Comment: maybe is components bug.Why donw you cread a menu item with type link and put it as above so as to navigate to the right link? Which is the component?

Comment: I did create a type link and the same thing happened. The url for the views i'm talking is index.php/juste-un-autre-bouton?view=donation. So the problem would come from the component view.html.php?